# How to set up active theme for plugin test in October Cms

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I'm trying to write a test for twig filter.
To do that I need to load a theme from a fixture folder
`plugins/matchish/myplugin/tests/fixtures/themes/test`

Here how I set up the test

```
class TwigTest extends PluginTestCase {

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        Config::set('cms.themesPath', __DIR__ . '/../fixtures/themes');
        Config::set('cms.activeTheme', 'test');
        Event::flush('cms.theme.getActiveTheme');
        Theme::resetCache();
    }
...
```

Now I'm getting an error `active theme not found`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getActiveTheme` and `setActiveTheme`

```php
// store old code once your testing done it should return to default theme
$oldTheme = Theme::getActiveTheme();
Theme::resetCache();
Theme::setActiveTheme('<theme.code>');

// at last 
Theme::setActiveTheme($oldTheme);
```

may be this should help.

Comment: It doesn't work because it looking theme in `themes/test` but fixture theme is in `plugins/matchish/myplugin/tests/fixtures/themes/test`

Comment: hmm even after setting `Config::set('cms.themesPath'` it looks there

Comment: hmm any way you give me minimal your test-suit i can use in my local to check that problem.